# I want an existing program work for two external processes as a child

Tags: c

I have a program that pipes two child processes. But I want these two processes (child) as external independent C program.

I want to connect the output of first process to input of a pipe and connect the input of second process as output of first pipe

Basically I want a program that works like this command in unix:

```
./myprogram prog1 | prog2
```

This is the code:

As I am a beginner, I took return value of prog1 and dup2 the output to the Standard Input of pipe and gave value to of the standard output to prog2 and tried to connect in prog2 program through dup2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
  printf("%s \n", argv[2]);

  int pipefd[2], status, done = 0;
  int cpid;
  pipe(pipefd);

  cpid = fork();

  if (cpid == 0) {
    // Child 1 - Process 1
    close(pipefd[0]);
    dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp(argv[1], argv[1], (char *)NULL);
  }

  cpid = fork();

  if (cpid == 0) {
    // Child 2 - Process 2
    close(pipefd[1]);
    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    execlp(argv[2], argv[2], (char *)NULL);
  }

  close(pipefd[0]);
  close(pipefd[1]);

  waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
  waitpid(-1, &status, 0);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the processes. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: The RoT applies to your code; each child should close both file descriptors for the pipe before using `execlp()`.  You should also have code that reports an error and exits after each `execlp()`.  However, it isn't clear what problem you're having.  With or without the changes, when I remove the unused variable `done` and check that `argc` is 3 (command name, command 1, command 2), the code works. (I called the source `pipe79.c` and compiled and ran `pipe79 ls head`, and that lists the two programs and the first 10 files.) . What is your problem?

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
  printf("%s \n", argv[2]);`   Do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters

Comment: you might want to look into `popen()` to help reduce the work load of the code